# Different entity/proxy dirs for Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am using doctrine 2 in my project, but I separate all my modules into different folders so the doctrine 2 entities are located in different directories depending on which module they belong to.

I am wondering if it is possible to change the Doctrine2 entity and proxy directory setting while using the existing connecting to the database. I have looked into the EntityManager class but can not see a function to update the configuration.

If there is no built in solution, does anyone know if this function would work in the EntityManager class:

```
public function updateConfiguration(Configuration $config)
{
    $this->config = $config;

    $metadataFactoryClassName = $config->getClassMetadataFactoryName();
    $this->metadataFactory = new $metadataFactoryClassName;
    $this->metadataFactory->setEntityManager($this);
    $this->metadataFactory->setCacheDriver($this->config->getMetadataCacheImpl());

    $this->proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory($this,
            $config->getProxyDir(),
            $config->getProxyNamespace(),
            $config->getAutoGenerateProxyClasses());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I's not clear what you exactly mean, but I will give it a try.

The databaseconnection is part of the EntityManager but they are not the same. Making changes to a databaseconnection is, as far as I know, not possible if the connection is already established.

You must be sure you have setup all configurations before you create an instance of the EntityManger. You can define your configuration as flexible as you want, but once the entitymanager is created you can't change it (correct me if I'm wrong). If you do so it can cause problems with other entities it already loaded and, for example, your flush calls could fail.

If you want to load entities from different location  you can work with the Doctrine classloader. Assign all entities of a module to a namespace and load that namespace from any location on your filesystem.

Small code example

```
// Doctrine module
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine', "/var/www/library/Doctrine/");
$classLoader->register();

// User modules
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('User', "/var/www/modules/models/User/");
$classLoader->register();

// Page module
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Page', "/some/path/to/different/modules/models/Page/");
$classLoader->register();
```

I don't see the use of changing the settings of your EntityManager during a request. If you have to do that, you're trying to fix your problem at the wrong place. I've never even tried it and don't want to anyway :).

Maybe I didn't understand your question. If so, please let me know :).

Answer (score 1):

One can retrieve $config from Entity manager like this:

```
$config = $em->getConfiguration();
```

To dynamically update entities paths try this (i've not tried it myself):

```
$driverImpl = new Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver(array(
    APP_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .  'entities'
));
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
```

P.S> I think this should work but I've not tried this so plz correct me if this wrong.